# dot (eg. reponse.title) property is not working on response object got from http service in angular 2

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular2-template, angular2-services, angular2-directives

I received response object from http service in angular 2 and if i try to console response.prop, it is not working and it is showing following error:

> D:/ABC/angular-training/angular_cli/src/app/shared/footer/footer.component.ts (16,28): Property 'prop' does not exist on type '{}'.)

But when I do response["prop"] then I get my value.

Here is my code:

```
export class FooterComponent {
  constructor(private httpService : HttpService) {
  this.httpService.getData("http://127.0.0.1:8887/footer.json").then(response => {
      console.log(response);//shows object 
      console.log(response.prop);//not works
      console.log(response["prop"]);//works fine
    });
  }
}
```

here is my Httpservice code:

```
export class HttpService {
private Title = URL;// URL to web api

constructor(private http: Http) { } 

getData(url="this.Title"): Promise<{}> {
return this.http.get(url)
           .toPromise()
           .then(response => 
             response.json()
           )
           .catch(this.handleError);
}

private handleError(error: any): Promise<any> {
console.error('An error occurred', error); 
return Promise.reject(error.message || error);
}
}
```

Also this is JSON response from server:

```
{
"footerLinks"  : {
  "social":[{
    "text":"Google",
    "link":"www.google.com"
  },
  {
    "text":"Facebook",
    "link":"www.facebook.com"
  },
  {
    "text":"Twitter",
    "link":"www.Twiiter.com"
  },
 {
    "text":"Pinterest",
    "link":"www.Pinterest.com"
  },
  {
    "text":"LinkedIn",
    "link":"www.linkedin.com"
  }]

}
}
```

Comment: How DOES your response look like? That would help to tell why it's not working as you wish :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to declare the type of `response`.

Try below,

```
response =>

to

(response : {prop: <string or what ever type>}) =>
```

This way Typescript compiler will know what is the type of your response object.

Hope this helps!!

Answer (score 0):

your response probably looks like json but is actually a string.

check the type with

```
console.log(typeof response);
```

try also ..

```
response.json()
```

or

```
JSON.parse(response);
```

You may need to add the JSON response header on the server response.

Comment: typeof response is Object.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned, your response is an Object (inside an Object), that is why you need to access the data with `console.log(response["prop"]);` as that is how we access nested objects.

Not knowing exactly what you want to extract from your response, if you want the array only, do this:

Service:

```
getData(url="this.Title"): Promise<{}> {
   return this.http.get(url)
      .toPromise()
      .then(response => response.json().footerLinks['social'])
      .catch(this.handleError);
}
```

If you want to preserve the Object `social`, which contains the array just leave `['social']` out from the above code. But I assume you only want the array, as the object `social` actually does not contain anything else than the array.

Component:

```
links: any[] = [];

this.httpService.getData("http://127.0.0.1:8887/footer.json")
  .then(response => {
     this.links = response;
  });
}
```

and you can iterate the array:

```
<div *ngFor="let link of links">
  {{link?.text}} {{link?.link}}
</div>
```

Notice that I used the **[safe navigation operator](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html#!#safe-navigation-operator)**, that prevents app throwing error in case of null values.